# Why output voltage of power adaptor is increasing when more load is applied instead of dropping?

Tags: power-supply

I use a cheap [power adaptor 5v 3Amp](https://m.aliexpress.com/s/item/32700939534.html?spm=a2g0n.orderList.0.0.sUpOvT&#autostay) When I power arduino with modules it is stable 5.4V but when I add [thermal printer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/597) that consume 1.5Amp peak output voltage is going 6.7V (when it is printing or sleeping). Also I have seen this when was powering some 1W relays. When I disconnect it it need some minutes to go back on 5.4V. I measure  vout with multimeter always onload. This may damage other modules. What may cause this and how to deal with it?

Comment: This is probably because the adapter internally compensates for the cable drop. To obtain a constant output voltage at the end of a 1-m cable on cell phone chargers for instance, the adapter manufacturer includes a circuit that senses the output current and increases \$V_{out}\$'s setpoint as the current \$I_{out}\$ also increases. With a well-calibrated circuit, \$V_{out}\$ is almost flat in relationship to the output current. Without comp. you would see \$V_{out}\$ falling because of the cable drop. The comp. is purposely slowed down to avoid oscillations once the loop is closed.

Comment: Get a better adapter. There's a reason the one you have was cheap.

Answer (score 1):

That [AliExpress page for the mains power adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1PCS-5V3A-AC-100V-240V-Converter-Adapter-DC-5V-3A-3000mA-Power-Supply-EU-Plug-5/32700939534.html) says the seller's specification for the output voltage is **5V +/- 5%**. Even your 5.4V measurement is higher than that specification, without mentioning the 6.7V measurement!

> This may damage other modules

Agreed. It might be interesting to see the output voltage on an oscilloscope, in case your multimeter is being confused by (for example) increasing AC ripple superimposed on a DC voltage etc. However, whatever is happening to that 5V output under high load, I would not risk using that mains power adapter.

> What may cause this

**Faulty power adapter** - either a faulty unit, or a faulty design. Unless you open the unit (obviously this is a *risk due to the high voltages inside!*), then reverse engineer the design, and then make appropriate measurements to find the actual root cause, then I don't see how you can be sure of the internal reason for that behaviour.

> how to deal with it

Either open the power supply (and therefore lose any warranty and incur the *risk of working near high voltages*), find the cause of the problem yourself and then design a fix - which I don't recommend, but I don't know your level of skill, what safety training you have received, or whether this is something that you might want to do; or **replace the mains power supply with one from a more trustworthy supplier**.

FYI even for my hobby projects, I never buy no-name power supplies from AliExpress, eBay etc. due to exactly these risks. The possibility of them damaging the rest of the project is just too high for me. :-(